# Finding the shortest path between two points on a grid, using Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, shortest-path, referential-transparency

This is a problem that I can easily enough solve in a non-functional manner.

But solving it in Haskell is giving me big problems. Me being inexperienced when it comes to functional programming is surely a reason.

The problem:

I have a 2D field divided into rectangles of equal size. A simple grid. Some rectangles are empty space (and can be passed through) while others are impassable. Given a starting rectangle *A* and a destination rectangle *B*, how would I calculate the shortest path between the two? Movement is possible only vertically and horizontally, in steps a single rectangle large.

How would I go about accomplishing this in Haskell? Code snippets certainly welcome, but also certainly not neccessary. And links to further resources also very welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd represent the grid as a list of lists, type `[[Bool]]`.  And I'd define a function to know if a grid element is full:

```
type Grid = [[Bool]]
isFullAt :: Grid -> (Int, Int) -> Bool  -- returns True for anything off-grid
```

Then I'd define a function to find neighbors:

```
neighbors :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
```

To find non-full neighbors of `point` you can filter with `filter (not . isFullAt) $ neighbors point`.

At this point I'd define two data structures:

- Map each point to `Maybe Cost`
- Store all points with known cost in a heap

Initialize with only the start square *A* in the heap, with cost zero.

Then loop as follows:

- Remove a min-cost square from the heap.
- If it's not already in the finite map, add it and its cost `c`, and add all the non-full neighbors to the heap with cost `c+1`.

When the heap is empty, you will have the costs of all reachable points and can look up *B* in the finite map.  (This algorithm may be called "Dijkstra's algorithm"; I've forgotten.)

You can find finite maps in `Data.Map`.  I assume there's a heap (aka priority queue) somewhere in the vast library, but I don't know where.

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: This definitely sounds Dijkstra's algorithm, or at least a variation of it.

Comment: Sounds like the A* algorithm.
(I can't seem to post the wikipedia link correctly).

Answer (score 3):

Well, your types will determine your algorithms.

What data type do you want to use to represent the grid? A two-dimensional array? A list of lists? A tree? A graph?

If you just want shortest path in a directed graph, using something from the FGL (functional graph package) would be best.